# No cached version of android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1 available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, build-dependencies

I have to work in offline mode so I synced the gradle when I was online and turned off the internet and tried to run the app but this error appeared again

I've noticed that anything with the prefix "annotationProcessor" doesn't get cached or something, is there a way to work completely in offline mode after downloading everything I need?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Offline work box is unchecked at gradle settings

With check Command-line Options not contains `--offline`

Also You can download library file (.jar) and save in **app\libs** folder

Then at android studio project viewer right click the jar file and click "add as library".

Comment: But everything else get cached.. why this particular library isn't cached automatically?

Comment: I agree with  you the dependencies from annotationProcessor scope are not cached, don't know why ?

Comment: actually, I reboot and it's ok now

Comment: mb you'll have to add GRADLE_USER_HOME as env variable too